# Is it possible to have to MYSQL servers running on one physical server?

Tags: mysql

I have a fast server with 8 CPU cores (and enough RAM). However this does speedup the MySQL-database, it does have its limits.

So, I was thinking to setup a second Mysql-server on the same server. Is this possible? And will this speedup the databases I run on the server. Ofcourse I have to select which databases will be run under MySql-1 and which will run under MySQL-2.

The server: Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Webmin v1.720

---

Thanks for the reactions.

It seems it isn't possible to run two MySQL-servers on one machine, without slowing it down. That's what I understand from the given replies. So that's why I started to think, that splitting up a very large database would increase the looking-up-speed, even when the database is running on the same machine, but under different MySQL-database-server software.

It seems to be the best that, if I need to split up the database, I have to setup another database-server-machine, right?

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes. "And will this speedup the databases I run on the server?" No. A well designed database speeds up the results of your queries ;) Why do you assume MySQL is doing so badly performance wise that you need to change the way a normal SQL server works? I would assume queries need to be optimized. Use the "describe" command to evaluate your queries. If any show "using temp file or using sort" and NOT "eq_ref" or "ref" focus on your queries.

Comment: I had big speed differences between queries with a well designed index and one without. And we are talking tables with 2, 3 million records that came back after 25+ seconds that only needed 0.5 after the alteration.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL scales up to use many cores and many GB of ram. 
Adding a separate instance won't make any difference to performance.
If you are wanting to get more performance, there are numerous configuration parameters to try.

The Percona wizard is a great starting place : https://tools.percona.com/wizard

Also the documentation for tuning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html

Comment: Neither will splitting a database or putting 2 databases on 2 machines ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to run a second mysql server is to use a virtual machine, but this is slower for database servers. Why do you think that you need a second server? Please describe exactly what you want to achieve.